# Update table with data after value selected from the dropdownlist (asp.net mvc)

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I am just  starting to work with asp.net mvc and I am trying to understand the logic between views and controllers.
I have the table with the data that I am getting from the db shown on my page and I am also have the dropdown on my page. I would like to update my table according to the value selected from the dropdown (for example if user selects T3) the data for T3 shows in the table.
I can't quite understand how I can pass the value selected from the dropdown and how to the controller and how to update my sql query with this new value. Is it suppose to be in the same index method or it should be the different one. I would appreciate any help and ideas. Thank you in advance.

Here is my model:

```
    public class TestModel
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string serial{ get; set; }
        public string pr { get; set; }
    }
```

Here is my Controller: First sql string I am using to get data for the dropdown and the second one to get data for the table itself.

```
    public class TestController : Controller
    {
     public List<TestModel> Test = new List<TestModel>();
     public List<TableModel> Table = new List<TableModel>();
  

        
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            try
            {

                String connectionString = "bbbb";
                using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
                {
                    connection.Open();
                    String sql2 = "SELECT * FROM db WHERE detail = 1";
                    using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sql2, connection))
                    {
                        using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                        {
                            while (reader.Read())
                            {
                                TestModel test= new TestModel();
                                test.id = Convert.ToInt32("" + reader[0]);
                                test.name = "" + reader[1];
                                test.serial = "" + reader[3];
                                test.pr = "" + reader[4];
                                Test.Add(test);
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    String sql = "SELECT * FROM bb1";
                    using (SqlCommand command1 = new SqlCommand(sql, connection)) { 
                    using(SqlDataReader reader1 = command1.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        while (reader1.Read())
                        {
                            TableModel tablemod = new TableModel();
                            tablemod.id = Convert.ToInt32("" + reader1[0]);
                            tablemod.tr = "" + reader1[2];
                            tablemod.pr = "" + reader1[4];
                            tablemod.req = "" + reader1[5];
                            tablemod.test = "" + reader1[6];
                            tablemod.method = "" + reader1[7];
                            tablemod.sport = "" + reader1[8];
                            tablemod.timer = "" + reader1[9];
                            tablemod.ra = "" + reader1[10];
                            tablemod.calib = "" + reader1[12];
                            Table.Add(tablemod);
                            }
                    }
                    }

                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("exception:" + ex.ToString());
            }


            ViewData["dropdown"] = TestCell;
            ViewData["table"] = Table;
            

            return View();
        }
    }
```

And here is the view:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="eng">
<head>
some styles go there
</head>

<body>
    <div class="table">

                <div>
                    <select asp-for="@Model.id" asp-items="(@ViewData["dropdown"] as IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)"  id="UserId" class="form-control " >
                        <span asp-validation-for="@Model.id"></span>
                        @foreach (var item in @ViewData["dropdown"] as IEnumerable<TestModel>)
                        {
                            <option class="others" value="@item.id&&@item.serial&&@item.pr">@item.fname</option>

                        }
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div><input id="serial" type="text"/></div>
                <div><input id="pr" type="text"/></div>               



            </div>






        </div>



        <table class="table ">
            <thead>
            <th data-field="tr" data-sortable="true">TR</th>
            <th data-field="pr" data-sortable="true">Priority</th>
            <th data-field="req" data-sortable="true">Requestor</th>
            <th data-field="test" data-sortable="true">Test Name</th>
            <th data-field="method" data-sortable="true">Description</th>
            <th data-field="sport" data-sortable="true">Failed Part</th>
            <th data-field="timer" data-sortable="true">Emission</th>
            <th data-field="ra" data-sortable="true">Rating</th>
            <th data-field="calib" data-sortable="true">Calibration</th>
            </thead>

             <tbody>
                @foreach (var item in @ViewData["table"] as IEnumerable<TableModel>)
                {
                    <tr>
                        <td>@item.trnum</td>
                        <td>@item.priority</td>
                        <td>@item.requestor</td>
                        <td>@item.testname</td>
                        <td>@item.description</td>
                        <td>@item.failed</td>
                        <td>@item.emission</td>
                        <td>@item.rating</td>
                        <td>@item.calibration</td>
                        <td>@item.eas</td>
                        <td>@item.recorder</td>




                    </tr>
                }

            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>

</body>
</html>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var $table = $('#fresh-table')
    var $alertBtn = $('#alertBtn')



    $(function () {
        $table.bootstrapTable({
            classes: 'table table-hover table-striped',
            toolbar: '.toolbar',

            search: true,
            showRefresh: true,
            showToggle: true,
            showColumns: true,
            pagination: true,
            height: $(window).height(),
            striped: true,
            sortable: true,
            pageSize: 10,
            pageList: [8, 10, 25, 50, 100],

            formatShowingRows: function (pageFrom, pageTo, totalRows) {
                return ''
            },
            formatRecordsPerPage: function (pageNumber) {
                return pageNumber + ' rows visible'
            }
        })

        $(window).resize(function () {
            $table.bootstrapTable('resetView', {
                height: $(window).height(),

            })
        })

    })

    $(function () {
        $('#fresh-table').bootstrapTable()
    })
    $("#UserId").change(function () {
        var selectedid = $("#UserId option:selected").val().split("&&");
        var serialNumber = selectedid[1];
        var projectNumber = selectedid[2];
        $('#serialNumber').val(serialNumber);
        $('#projectNumber').val(projectNumber);
    });

</script>
```

Comment: Hi @Marfa, The sql should be like:`select * from tableName where xxx=selectedvalue`, which `tableName` you want to display? What does the condition `xxx` in your table? Also, for the `selectedvalue` does it exist in the current `tableName` or in any other related table?

Comment: Hello, I am trying to display the data from tablemod. The selected value exists in this table. Yes, I understand that my query suppose to be like that select * from tableName where xxx=selectedvalue. I think my question is how I pass the selected value back from the view to the controller to be able to use it in the query.

Comment: Hi @Marfa, if you just need send the selected value, for example maybe pass the `id`, just add one line in end of the `$("#UserId").change()` function: `window.location.href ="/url?selectedValue="+selectedid[0]`. Then be sure your action contanis parameter:`public IActionResult YourActionName(int selectedValue)`.